# Change the color of a previous row in a For Each

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a filled DatagridView and the following code to check time lapses between rows.

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridViewHistoric.Rows
    If i = 0 Then
        TimeA = CUInt(dr.Cells("UNIX_time").Value)
    Else
        TimeB = CUInt(dr.Cells("UNIX_time").Value)
        If TimeB > TimeA + (Offset * 3600) Then
            'Found - Change color
            dr.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue

        End If
        TimeA = TimeB
    End If

i += 1
Next
```

That works ok, but now I need to change the color of the previous row that was found.

I can't figure out how meet that goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "for each" use "for x"

```
For x as Integer = 0 to Me.DataGridViewHistoric.Rows.count - 1
    If x = 0 Then
        TimeA = CUInt(DataGridViewHistoric.Rows(x).Cells("UNIX_time").Value)
    Else
        TimeB = CUInt(DataGridViewHistoric.Rows(x).Cells("UNIX_time").Value)
        If TimeB > TimeA + (Offset * 3600) Then
            DataGridViewHistoric.Rows(x).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            DataGridViewHistoric.Rows(x -1).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
        TimeA = TimeB
    End If
Next
```

The syntax might not be 100% - I'm doing this from memory, but you should get the gist.